# Merging second time, wanting to see conflicts again - for tortoisegit compare/diff tool

Tags: git, merge, branch, tortoisegit

Lets imagine a situation:

- Basic: Iam using Windows and tortoisegit configured to use beyondcompare as mergetool/difftool. I love the comfort.
- Two branches (master and my branch), already merged and conflicts resolved in the past. Conflicts resolved right in such a way, that the branches still do differ and thats OK!
- I would like to initiate merge into my branch again and invoke the conflicts-resolve-tool (set to BeyondCompare in tortoisegit) to resolve the conflicts differently, than it was done in the past!

... Basically I want to evoke beyondcompare on a file from branch master against my current branch and be able to save the result in my current branch (i dont want to modify master).

The desired behavior is only to:

- produce new commit, not to modify history (the conflict resolving strategy simply changed, but it was right in the past)
- evoke my beyond compare like if I would be resolving conflicts for my comfort of work

I already managed to do things like git checkout --patch, but that appears in the console window and I just get mad :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways: Cherry Pick, or Rebase.

Cherry Pick: need to select commits carefully.

Rebase: might need one more step "Reset Hard".

### Cherry Pick

1. The log

[image]

2. Cherry pick

[image]

3. Squash all commits and go

[image]

4. Get conflict and ...

[image]

5. The new commit

[image]

### Rebase

1. Reset hard to that commit which master was on.

[image]

2. Rebase test branch onto the commit which the branch is from.

[image]

3. Squash all commits and go

[image]

4. Get conflict and ...

[image]

5. The rest things are almost the same...